# Merge Replication in SQL2019 database is restored to new server NOT keeping_replication

Tags: replication, merge

Merge Replication in SQL2019 database is restored to new server NOT keeping_replication but in restored database we find MSmerge_cont_% system views.

The last part of the system view name appears to be like replication guid type values.
Restored database if a different database name and on a same version of SQL server.
No other evidence of merge replica metadata.

When I try to do a select on the view, it says `invalid object` type error.

Is this MSmerge_contents table of original database and how do you drop these invalid system views?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.